# Как мне найти и просмотреть содержимое диска D в Linux?

Tags: linux, install, disk

На моём старом компьютере(32bit, 1,7Ghz, 1.3Gb ОЗУ) стояла windows 7. Но тот же самый браузер запускался через 10 минут. Я посмотрел, какие есть лёгкие linux дистрибутивы. Выбрал AntiX. Установил на компьютер через загрузочную флешку. Браузер, ютуб летает. Но вот я захожу в файловый менеджер и не могу найти содержимое диска D. Я посмотрел много видео по этой теме, понял что у linux не такая файловая система. Что такое как в папке media должны быть папки с содержимым всех дисков, в том числе флешки и диска D. Но когда нажимаю на папки этих дисков, то мне пишет что отказано в доступе и открывается пустая папка на которую я нажимал. Пожалуйста помогите, где я могу найти содержимое диска D, а может оно исчезло, пропало. Но когда я установливал linux, то думал что сотрётся только диск C, на который я устанавливал linux. А может диск D это просто раздел диска C? Где я могу найти содержимое диска D в linux?

Comment: Первый SATA-диск в виде файла блочного устройства обычно находится по адресу `/dev/sda`, разделы нумеруются от `/dev/sda1` и так далее, посмотреть список разделов устройства и информацию о них можно командой наподобие `fdisk -l /dev/sda` (запускать от имени root конечно же) — вот и смотрите, есть ли в выводе этой команды что-то похожее на нужный вам диск D. В папке media ничего само себе не появляется, диски нужно сперва примонтировать

Comment: @andreymal Это значит что один из этих sda1 и sda2 дисков и есть диск D? Я извиняюсь, я новичок в этом деле, Как можно запустить от имени root? И как их примонтировать можно, через какое меню?

Comment: Диски монтируется не через меню, а через команду `mount`. Вам стоило бы почитать что-нибудь по основам линукса и поэкспериментировать в виртуальной машине, прежде чем устанавливать линукс на реальный компьютер...

Comment: покажите что выводит `lsblk -f`

Comment: Ну и касательно «думал что сотрётся только диск C» — это зависит от того, какую разметку диска вы выбирали при установке. Я вот сейчас запустил установку AntiX в виртуальной машине и вижу, что он предлагает настроить разметку разделов вручную или тупо стереть весь диск — вам лучше знать, что вы сделали)

Comment: Я сейчас поставил AntiX в виртуальной машине и вижу, что он автоматически прописал ntfs-разделы в файл `/etc/fstab` и создал нужные папки в media — а значит команда наподобие `sudo mount /media/нужнаяПапка` должна успешно примонтировать указанный раздел. Если после этого в файловом менеджере нажать кнопочку обновления (Rescan directory contents) — у папки появится зелёный кружочек, обозначающий статус монтирования, и она станет успешно открываться. Скриншот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83TOj.png